# How should I define random variable when doing an experiment?

Tags: probability

I have difficulty understanding the relationship between probability function and random variable. Suppose the case where 2 people are selected out of 100 people. Then the sample space is $\{a_1,\ a_2,\ \cdots\,\ a_{100}\}^2$, the probability of choosing each ordered pair will be equal to 1/10000.

I want to find the sum of the ages of the two selected people. So where should each person's age be set? Perhaps I can set the random variable to be the sum of the ages of the two selected people. But where does the valuation for the chosen outcome come from? I was thinking of putting the sample space to a set like $\{13,\ 42,\ 31,\ 66,\ ...\}^2$, but the set doesn't allow duplicate values, which seems inappropriate. How can I construct the probability space in this case?

Comment: You can still use $\mathbb{N}$ as the set of the possible outcomes. You will have infinitely many outcomes that have probability 0, but all the possible outcomes are included inside. Otherwise if you want an explicit set, I think you have no other choice than computing all the possibles sum of ages that appear. If you want to reduce to a finite set, take the sum of the two highest ages as the upper bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a 100 people and their ages then you have $\binom{100}{2}$ pairs of people. So your probability space should be the $\binom{100}{2}$ pairs of ages (of course there might be duplicates so that makes it more likely to have a particular pair and corresponding sum). Then the random variable $X$ would take the sum of the values in the pair.